# django-filter for Boolean

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

I am a beginner to Django and doing a learning project which is a booking system. Can anyone recommend me an open source django project where I can check the source code for best practices. Thanks in advance

When I use the code below, get method gets "on" or "off". How can it be "True"/"False"?

Model.py

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    ...
    is_xxx_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=False,null=False)
    is_contracted_by_yy= models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=False,null=False)
    is_zz_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=False,null=False)
```

Filter.py

```
class MymodelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ['is_xxx_approved', 'is_contracted_by_yy', 'is_zz_approved']
        exclude = [
            'name',
            'address',
            'phone',
            'email',]
        filter_overrides = {
            models.BooleanField: {
                'filter_class': django_filters.BooleanFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'widget': forms.CheckboxInput,
                },
            },
        }
```

Template

```
<div class="filter_index">
    {% with field=filter.form.is_xxx_approved %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    {% endwith %}

</div>
<div class="filter_index">
    {% with field=filter.form.is_contracted_by_yy %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    {% endwith %}
</div>
<div class="filter_index">
    {% with field=filter.form.is_zz_approved %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    {% endwith %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me is being asked, but I will say that you should generally avoid `CheckboxInput` when using filters. In short, they *always* evaluate to true/false, and there's no way to submit an empty value for the filter field. For example, if you submit an empty form, you would effectively construct this queryset:

```py
Mymodel.objects \
    .filter(is_xxx_approved=False) \
    .filter(is_contracted_by_yy=False) \
    .filter(is_zz_approved=False)
```

Although you might have reasonably expected to construct this queryset:

```py
Mymodel.objects.all()
```

Again, this specifically is an issue with `CheckboxInput` and its inability to represent an empty value. Instead, you should be using the default `Select` widget, or switch to a `RadioSelect`.

Additionally, it's redundant to use both the `Meta.fields` and `Meta.exclude` options. I would recommend using `Meta.fields`.